# Find the user, repo and path from a github url

Tags: javascript, github, github-api

I need to be able to get the user, repo and path from a github url (to a file in the repo) that is pasted into a form, to be able to make api requests on it. e.g. https://github.com/HubSpot/BuckyClient/blob/master/README.md

I've started writing some regex to try and just locate the parts of the url, but this seems like a brittle solution given there are many formats of github urls.

Is there an api method I've not found, something like getRepoFromUrl(), or another more reliable way I can extract this information from the url provided? I'm using node/javascript.

Thanks

Comment: A bit similar to this regex? (https://gist.github.com/dhermes/4992764)

Comment: Similar, but I need the path of the file as well

Comment: What file? (I am asking because your question didn't mention or involve a file)

Comment: "I need to be able to get the user, repo and path". See the example url - it's to a github file. I'll update the question to clarify

Comment: I confirm you should be able to extract the information you seek from the content of the html page send back by GitHub for that url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a regex, could you rather use list a specific repo url using the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-user-repositories), in order to parse the JSON answer, getting various fields which should include the information you seek:

```
"owner": {
      "login": "octocat",

"name": "Hello-World",
"full_name": "octocat/Hello-World",
```

---

Since the input data is an url, check what the metadata of the html page of that url includes.
For my repo https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything, I see:

```
<title>VonC/compileEverything</title>
<meta content="VonC/compileEverything" property="og:title" />
...
```

That should allow to get back at least the name of the user and the repo name.

Comment: Yes but the issue is how do I reliably get the repo/user from the url

Comment: Because the GitHub api would give you that information reliably

Comment: But I need the username or repo name before I can query the api. I can't query the api with the URL

Comment: Thanks. However I feel like this is also a brittle solution as to get the path I need to look for dom elements which clearly could change. For now I'm actually going to stick with the url regex to save loading and parsing the whole page. I'll need to keep thinking for a more robust solution

Comment: I agree with you. Maybe the GitHub support might have a more robust solution to propose?