# how do I parse github url with javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to parse a GitHub URL like `https://github.com/<USERNAME>/<REPO>` , but however my frontend is done in reactjs , so I am trying to figure out the following code in python for javascript `url.rsplit('/',1)[1].split('.')[0]`

Comment: Have you tried writing any primitive code and watch the results yourself?

Comment: regex, but i dont want to rely on regex

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the user, repo and path from a github url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28852056/find-the-user-repo-and-path-from-a-github-url)

Comment: split("/") and read the two indexes or simple reg exp

Answer (score 2):

This will do to get `<REPO>` as the result. Not python equivalent code, but will work

```js
const url = 'https://github.com/<USERNAME>/<REPO>';
const repoName = url.split('/').pop();
console.log(repoName);
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the url has any query string parameters or the repo isn't the last part of the url

Answer (score 0):

The `URL` class that's built into the browser can do most of the basic url parsing for you and would help make sure the repo string doesn't contain any query parameters and the like.

```js
const url = new window.URL("https://github.com/username/repo.git");
// Split the path by '/' and remove any empty array items 
// Empty items might be caused if the user enters '//' as part of the url
const pathArr = url.pathname.split("/").filter(Boolean);
const repo = pathArr[1];

console.log(repo)
```

More information about the `URL` class is available here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

Comment: is possible without URL since the urls are stored in a database , and I cant hit each url to retrieve the links user/repo

Comment: @anaosuna making an instance of the url class won't actually hit the url. It merely parses it. If your backend is in nodejs then you can also import the URL class from the 'url' module. Python has its own 'urllib'

Answer (score 0):

In the case of having to take userName and repoName, you can use:

```js
const repoUrl = "https://github.com/<userName>/<repoName>"

const userName = repoUrl.split('/').slice(-2)[0]
const repoName = repoUrl.split('/').pop()

console.log(userName, repoName)
```